# Report in VF page is not coming in the lightning

Tags: lightning

I have added the report in VF page by using the iframe tag,if i switched into lightning this page is showing as blank.How i can fix this issues

```
        <apex:outputPanel id="MissingAttRpt" >                 
            <apex:iframe src="/{!reportId}?isdtp=lt" scrolling="true"  height="650px"  width="100%" id="iframe"/>   
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
```

Comment: VF iFrames are not recommended in Lightning.  See this [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_known_issues)

Comment: What is the workaround for this ?

Comment: There is no workaround.